# Android Async Task ArrayList Manipulation Causes IndexOutOfBounds in onDraw

Tags: java, android, asynchronous

I am using an Async Task to Get Objects from a Database and Put them into an ArrayList. I am also using this same ArrayList  to draw things on Screen. This is done through a for loop, that loops through the array. It seems that when the Async task is started, it clears the array list to populate it with the new Objects whilst the for loop is running sometimes, which results in an indexOutOfBounds exception.

How do I prevent this behaviour?

ASYNC:

```
    // GET ORDER LISTINGS: LIST ORDERS IN RANGE
    public void listOrders() {
        if (Utility.getCurrentLocation() != null) {
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    new ListOrdersTask().execute((Void) null);
                }
            });
        } else {
            // Cannot Determine Location
            showMessage("Cannot Determine Location.");
        }
    }

    class ListOrdersTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {
        private void postData() {
            if (user.loggedIn) {
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(
                        "http://cyberkomm.ch/sidney/php/getOrders.php");
                try {
                    ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(
                            4);
                    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("LatMin", String
                            .valueOf(user.latitude - seekRange)));
                    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("LatMax", String
                            .valueOf(user.latitude + seekRange)));
                    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("LongMin", String
                            .valueOf(user.longitude - seekRange)));
                    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("LongMax", String
                            .valueOf(user.longitude + seekRange)));
                    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                            new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity()
                                    .getContent()));
                    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
                    String line = "";
                    while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                        sb.append(line);
                        break;
                    }
                    in.close();
                    responseString = sb.toString();
                    responseString = responseString.substring(0,
                            responseString.length() - 1);

                    // Handle Response
                    user.orderList.clear();
                    String[] tmp1 = responseString.split("\\|");
                    for (String s : tmp1) {
                        String[] tmp2 = s.split(",");
                        Order tmp3 = new Order();
                        tmp3.orderId = tmp2[0];
                        tmp3.placerName = tmp2[1];
                        tmp3.itemName = tmp2[2];
                        tmp3.payment = tmp2[3];
                        tmp3.locationString = tmp2[4];
                        if (user.orderList.size() < 1) {
                            tmp3.yPos = (int) ((user.orderList.size() * orderHeight) + (barHeight * 1.1f)); //
                            // Shadow of Bar is why 1.1f
                            tmp3.xPos = 0;
                        } else {
                            tmp3.yPos = user.orderList.get(user.orderList
                                    .size() - 1).yPos
                                    + orderHeight
                                    + (orderHeight / 7); // + Gap
                            tmp3.xPos = 0;
                        }

                        tmp3.image = orderImage1;
                        user.orderList.add(tmp3);
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e("log_tag", "Error:  " + e.toString());
                }
            } else {
                // Must Login
                showMessage("Must Login");
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
            postData();
            return null;
        }
    }
```

ON DRAW:

```
for (int i = 0; i < user.orderList.size(); ++i) {
                    if (user.orderList.size() > 0) {
                        textSize = scrnWidth / 25;
                        paint.setTextSize(textSize);
                        paint.setAlpha(255);
                        if (user.orderList.size() > 0) {
                            canvas.drawBitmap(user.orderList.get(i).image,
                                    user.orderList.get(i).xPos,
                                    user.orderList.get(i).yPos, paint);
                        }
                        paint.setAlpha(150);
                        if (user.orderList.size() > 0) {
                            canvas.drawText(
                                    user.orderList.get(i).itemName,
                                    user.orderList.get(i).xPos + orderHeight
                                            + (orderHeight / 10),
                                    (user.orderList.get(i).yPos + textSize * 1.85f),
                                    paint);
                        }
                        textSize = scrnWidth / 28;
                        paint.setTextSize(textSize);
                        if (user.orderList.size() > 0) {
                            canvas.drawText(
                                    "@" + user.orderList.get(i).placerName,
                                    user.orderList.get(i).xPos + orderHeight
                                            + (orderHeight / 10),
                                    (user.orderList.get(i).yPos
                                            + (textSize * 1.85f) + (textSize * 1.25f)),
                                    paint);
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Comment: can you post your code?

Comment: You should write a different List in the Background and then replace the old one with the update, when the Task is done. Synchronize the access (that is the complete drawing loop) while updating the view and replacing the list so they cannot interfere.

Comment: AS soon as i posted the question i figured that out. Thank you anyway. If you like you can post that as the answer so others can see :)

Comment: You need to lock around the user.orderList. On a side note, the statements for clearing and adding data to the list should follow each other immediately. Because you have code between these statements the risk of an empty list is much bigger. 

Also I would put the code for clearing the list and adding the items to the list in onPostExecute(). And use the String[] as a parameter for onPostExecute().

Comment: @Arno: indeed, and in that case the locking is no longer required, since then you are effectively putting read and write operations on the same thread, since onDraw() and onPostExecute() both run on main.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should write a different List in the Background and then replace the old one with the update, when the Task is done. Synchronize the access (that is the complete drawing loop) while updating the view and replacing the list so they cannot interfere.

Comment: If with "the task is done" you refer to onPostExecute() than synchronization is gotten for free, and no further locking is necessary, since onDraw() and onPostExecute() run on the same thread. Less is more ;-)

Comment: @Baske You're right. But I wanted to leave that to OP's decision **how** to do that. I don't know the rest of his code.

Comment: Absolutely true that he has a whole array of options that he should choose from, but I regularly see code that has locks all over the place "just to be sure". When I read or maintain code like that, the locks cause unnecessary confusion. But again, you are correct that OP should decide on the best solutions for his situation!